# Can the verb "mumble" be used to express "talking without voice" like some children do?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

> **[mumble](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mumble_1?q=mumble)** verb [intransitive, transitive] to speak or say
>   something in a quiet voice in a way that is not clear synonym mutter
>
> mumble (to somebody/yourself) I could hear him mumbling to himself.
>
> mumble something (to somebody/yourself) She mumbled an apology and
>   left.
>
> - speech ‘Sorry,’ she mumbled.
>
> mumble that… She mumbled that she was sorry.

But it seems that mumbling involves that people do speak but they don't speak loud enough, maybe they don't open their mouths big enough.

But some children speak with their mouths opening big but voicelessly. In that situation, can I say "**The child is mumbling**"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - mumbling refers to speech which is *inarticulate*, not *inaudible*.

- Speaking without sufficient volume is called *whispering*.
- Forming speech patterns with your lips without any sound at all is called *mouthing*.
- The vocal sounds made by very young children before they can speak is usually called "babbling" in informal settings, or "tunefully vocalising" by some speech and language experts.

Note that 'mouthing' is usually used transitively, eg "*she is mouthing the words*".

Comment: I think the word I am looking for is "mouthing" the child is 2 years old & she is very funny, she speaks as usual but tries to produce no sound, maybe just for fun.